# Como puedo migrar multiples proyectos de svn a git?

Tags: git, svn

Tengo un proyecto que tiene varios módulos (unos 6) en SVN pero están distribuidos en distintos repositorios, he clonado cada uno de ellos con sus historiales en mi local.
Pero no sé como subirlos todos juntos a un mismo repositorio con los historiales de cada uno a un repositorio GIT que tengo creado en Bitbucket.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: si has conseguido solución, publícala como respuesta! Está más que recomendado

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido hacerlo.
Me ha ayudado mucho la respuesta en este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si es la mejor manera, pero me ha funcionado. He hecho lo siguiente:

1. He clonado todos los repositorios que estaban dispersados en SVN con sus historiales.
2. He subido cada repositorio individualmente a repositorios GIT en Bitbucket.
3. He seguido los pasos del post que indicado anteriormente para fusionar todos los repositorios en uno solo.